# Setting only available variation automatically in woocommerce

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, product-variations

In woocommerce my goal is to set the variation attribute automatically if it's the only one available. I partially found a way to do it but strangely it only works with the first LI if I click on a second or other LI in the first table row the auto selection doesn't work.

```
<script>
  const firstRowItems = document.querySelectorAll('.variations tr:first-child li');
  firstRowItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Add a delay of 2 seconds before simulating the click
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Set up event listeners for the corresponding second row items that are not disabled
        const secondRowItems = document.querySelectorAll('.variations tr:nth-child(2) li:not(.disabled)');
        if (secondRowItems[index]) {
          secondRowItems[index].click();
        }
      }, 2000);
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm adding the delay so Swatches plugin has some time to sel disabled classes to disabled variations.